# dotnet restore not copying NETStandard.Library and other framework packages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have a PC which is not allowed to connect to any network. I need to work on this PC on a Net Standard project. I worked in this scenario before with Net Framework projects just using the nuget.exe options to save packages to a folder, copying the folder to the isolated PC and using nuget to restore packages from that folder.

But doing this with a Net Standard project using dotnet restore mechanism fails because there are missing packages like NETStandard.Library.

The command I used to create the offline package folder is:

```
dotnet restore solution.sln --packages offline_cache
```

And after copying the folder to the isolated machine I use:

```
dotnet restore solution.sln --source offline_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be running `dotnet publish` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Note that if you are using PackageReferences then `nuget restore` will only install the dependencies in your global cache, not copy them locally https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore